# How to permanently store parameter qs in 7-Zip for all users

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, compression, zip, 7-zip

I have a scenario where I use 7-Zip to store multiple files by a script to a 7z archive. I used a very old version that produced good compression results, but since the newer file sorting was enabled, the results are worse, which can be solved by forcing the old file sorting behaviour by specifying a parameter value called qs. If you set this value in the UI -> Add -> Parameters field, it is consistent for the current user.

What I am looking for is a solution for setting the qs parameter for all users permanently, not only the current user. Where are these parameter values actually stored, and how can they be saved for all users on that system, so that the **commandline-tool (not only the GUI)** will use them automatically? I do not want to alter all my scripts running on that system, so I seek for a place where the commandline-tool 7z.exe will look for the parameter.

I already tried

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\7-Zip\Compression\Options\7z]
"Options"="qs"
```

Without success. So which is the right place to set it?

Comment: This SourceForge discussion talks about getting settings to apply for all users. https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/16469428/  I haven't tried the proposed solution, but it might at least give you some ideas.